# regex grep filter with string

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have text like these :

> div class="ls-icon ls-item " data-ctrdot="214752854">
>   div class="ls-icon ls-item " data-ctrdot="213523235">
>   div class="ls-icon ls-item " data-ctrdot="788746365">
>   div class="ls-icon ls-item " data-ctrdot="332532436">

and i want to export :

> data-ctrdot="214752854">
>   data-ctrdot="213523235">
>   data-ctrdot="788746365">
>   data-ctrdot="332532436">

but i dont know why this

> grep -o 'data-ctrdot="\w*'

does not work .
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *does not work* you mean it outputs this:

```
data-ctrdot="214752854
data-ctrdot="213523235
data-ctrdot="788746365
data-ctrdot="332532436
```

Instead of

```
data-ctrdot="214752854">
data-ctrdot="213523235">
data-ctrdot="788746365">
data-ctrdot="332532436">
```

Then yes, it's broken. But perhaps you could just inject the last two characters into the grep expression?

```
grep -o 'data-ctrdot="\w*">'

data-ctrdot="214752854">
data-ctrdot="213523235">
data-ctrdot="788746365">
data-ctrdot="332532436">
```

Comment: so far * is a multiplicator, and \w is just matching a [0-9a-Z_] or so, so it is not matching " nor >.
Thus you can add \w.. to match the ending characters, or simplify the regex with data-ctrdot.* anyway

Comment: @user753642 you mean `\W`? (capital)

Comment: indeed you can use \w*\W\W (\W being the opposite of \w, that is class of characters matching non word letters)

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
awk '/data-ctrdot=/{print $NF}' file
```